# Setting a Postman collection variable from JSON response from AWS

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, postman

I'm trying to set a collection variable in Postman to store params from AWS.

The params in question from AWS all start with "x-amz", and when I try to store one of these values,  the console only returns:

**"ReferenceError: amz is not defined"**.

I'm trying to set it simply using the following:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.collectionVariables.set("x-amz-algorithm", jsonData.multipart_params.x-amz-algorithm);
```

How can I set this value without triggering the ReferenceError?

Answer (score 0):

`x-amz-algorithm` is not a valid attribute name because it contains `-`, the subtraction operator.

Try

```
jsonData.multipart_params["x-amz-algorithm"]
```